# Simple htaccess rule for rewriting the URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Im trying to achieve this

```
http://domain.com?q=page-slug to http://domain.com/page-slug
```

right now if I access this  `http://domain.com?q=page-slug` my webpage is working, but I want clean URls like `http://domain.com/page-slug`

I used this code in my htaccess but returning 500 error

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

any help please.

Answer (score 0):

Try this I am assuming you have index.php page which is handling the request.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)$ index.php?q=$1 [QSA,L]
```

If not index.php change to actual page you have.